# rails 3.1.3: rake aborts (couldn't parse YAML) when run first db:migrate (trying to run postgres locally on mac lion)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, postgresql

For a new project I'm trying to run postgres locally.

Mac Lion has Postgres installed  (9.1.2). I modified my path in .bash_profile (per another SO thread) so now I have no trouble creating a database or user using the psql utility.

I uninstalled and re-installed the pg gem (0.13.2) using `env ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64" gem install pg` per the excellent blog at http://blog.willj.net/2011/05/31/setting-up-postgresql-for-ruby-on-rails-development-on-os-x/

My Gemfile uses the pg gem for development, test, and production. I've run bundle install.

My database.yml looks like this (and the username and database names are correct and I verified I can access the database fr that username using the psql utility):

```
development:
 adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: ddchart_development
  pool: 5
  username: ddchart
  password:
```

(same for test and production, except _test and _production. Password is blank, right?)

When I run `bundle exec rake db:migrate` it aborts:

```
rake aborted!
couldn't parse YAML at line 8 column 10
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Password is not always blank. depends on your local database config.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you pasted the code correctly, there are errors in the code. For example, there's only one space before "adapter", but two before following lines.

In YAML, indentation matters.

Comment: good catch thank you! I had manually edited it when switching from sqlite to pg.